# how to remove specific subscribe in multiple subscribes list in angular 7 FormGroup valueChanges?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-forms, rxjs6

I am using angular 7 Multiple FormControl valueChanges subscribe function.

how do I remove or unsubscribe specific FormControl subscribe function.

```
FormControlsSubscribe(){
  const FormControlsArray = Object.keys(this.FGroup.controls);
     FormControlsArray.map(controlName => {
     const control = this.FGroup.controls[controlName] as FormControl;
     control.valueChanges.subscribe(change => {
        console.log(controlName + '>>>' + change);
     });
  });
};



RemoveControl(ControlKey: any) {
  this.FGroup.removeControl(ControlKey);
}
```

I expect the removed control unsubscribed;

Answer (score 0):

Given that you don't assign `control.valueChanges.subscribe` to any variable, you can't.

Moreover, you will have severe memory leaks with this code. You never close your subscriptions, this is a very dangerous way to manage them.

Comment: if any other way to detect the FormControl value changes, please suggest.

Comment: There are a lot of other ways. I'm not saying you're using the wrong way, I'm saying you're coding poorly (no offense intended). You have a design flaw and you need to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use takeUntil to unsubscribe automatically:

```
private unsubscribe$: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

control.valueChanges
pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
.subscribe(_ => {
  console.log(controlName + '>>>' + change);
});

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.unsubscribe$.next();
  this.unsubscribe$.complete();
}
```

or you can assign `control.valueChanges.subscribe` to a variable (Subscription) and unsubscribe that.

```
let subs: Subscription[] = [];

FormControlsArray.map(controlName => {
  const control = this.FGroup.controls[controlName] as FormControl;
  this.subs.push(control.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {}));
});

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subs.forEach(sub => sub.unsubscribe());
  this.subs = [];
}
```

Comment: it's not working, I except for dynamic FormControl add and remove concept if I remove the one control after I add the same control the Subscribe was triggering two times

Comment: On remove, you'll have to unsubscribe that remove item. I'm not sure how you write you code, but I found similar example for dynamic add / remove form control: https://github.com/udos86/ng-dynamic-forms/blob/master/projects/ng-dynamic-forms/core/src/lib/component/dynamic-form-control-container.component.ts